# Eclipse : Search With the Exact Matching String

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE , i need to search a String inside my Project .

So inside Eclipse , I clikced  Search Item from  Menu and Selected File and entered a String "exch" .

It is displaying all the results such as "exchange" , but i want to display only the Exact String matched "exch"

[image]

Comment: I think by "String" you mean "word".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the "Regular expression" checkbox, and surround your word with `\b` at the beginning and end which matches beginning and end (boundaries) of a word, so your search term will be `\bexch\b`

Comment: What if i want to much `\b@XmlEnumValue(*)\b` it doesn't work for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Check Regular expression and search `\sexch\s`

Comment: \s is whitespace only, it would miss `exch` surrounded by punctuation and operators